# При установке пакета через pip3, прерывается ошибкой Killed

Tags: pip, python-3.8, telethon, vds

Пытаюсь установить telethon через pip3, но возникает ошибка Killed. Все другие пакеты ставятся вроде нормально, а этот никак поставить не могу. Пробовал использовать флаг --no-cache-dir - тоже не помогает, пробовал переустановить, удалить, но никак, так как его не удается даже установить.
Памяти ОЗУ: 500мб,ОС: ubuntu, vds - сервер.

Comment: добавьте полный текст ошибки. версия питона какая ? #Requires: Python >=3.5

Answer (score 0):

После перезагрузки проблема была решена.